# I want to write a bashrc alias that launches commands in multiple new terminals

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu, jupyter

I have 3 parts for my workflow that I would like to alias to a single line ‘workflow’. Each command will run a server in terminal so I’ll need the command to open multiple tabs preferably on the same window.

I don’t know too much about writing bashrc scripts so I’m not sure how to put it into a single line. Essentially I want gnome-terminal —-tab —-tab —-tab to run and then for each tab run one of these; psql mydb, Jupyter lab, metabase.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "psql mydb" --tab -e "Jupyter lab" --tab -e "metabase"
```

Comment: What I ended up writing was very different. But it was due to issues with working directory. Having these phrases was super useful in helping me find the right commands to use!!